# apollo-server how to access datasource in koa/express middleware

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm new to the `apollo-server` world, so maybe I've taken something wrong.

in `apollo-server`, `DataSource` is meant to create and initialize by `ApolloServer`. But I also want to access some `DataSource` in the `koa` `middleware`. Let's say, I have a `DataSource` called `UserDataSource`, and this is how I create it with `ApolloServer`:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    dataSources:function(){
        return {
            user: new UserDataSource(),
        };
    },
});
// this is my middleware
async function auth(ctx, next){
    // Here I need to access `UserDataSource`

    // pass control down to apollo-server
    await next();
}

// koa server
const app = new Koa();
app.use(auth);
server.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

after this, I can access `dataSources.user` in `resolvers`. But some other `middleware` also need to access `UserDataSource`. Are there some official guides on how to achieve this?

**PS**, maybe I could manually create all the data sources in one `middleware`, and assign them to `ctx`. But I think this is a little hack.